# Why i fail to setNavigationOnClickListener to toolbar?

Tags: java, android

fail to setNavigationOnClickListener to toolbar

set a onclick event listener to toolbar's back icon

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
```

Comment: What you want to do with this listener ,My measn you want to trigger some event with toolbar back button icon?And post your code here .

Comment: yes, but your code still fail to work

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: @Kabir@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_todo);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle inState) {
        ...
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ...
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // do something
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```